# How can I get an MD5 hash in ColdFusion?

Tags: security, coldfusion, md5, hash

I'm trying to get an MD5 hash of a value in ColdFusion. I tried this code using the [Encrypt](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_e-g_01.html) function<sup>1</sup>:

```
<cfscript>
val = 1117;
md5 = Encrypt(val, 0, "MD5", "Hex");
</cfscript>
```

But I get an error:

> The MD5 algorithm is not supported by the Security Provider you have chosen.

How can I choose a different security provider?

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I know that MD5 isn't an *encryption* algorithm, but the ColdFusion folks don't seem to know that because they list it as a supported algorithm for the Encrypt function.  **Edit**: I didn't see the built-in [Hash](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions%5Fh-im%5F01.html#1105551) function but I saw the fact that Encrypt lists md5 and sha as supposedly supported algorithms, so I thought (incorrectly it turns out) that this was just how you got a hash in CF.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption.  Encryption is, by definition, undoable.  Hashing should be difficult enough that undoing it is impractical.  If you need to recover the original data, use encryption.  If you need to verify data (like files, or passwords) hashing is the way to go.

Regardless, use the hash() function for MD5, as Eddie has pointed out.

Comment: @Ben Doom: I fully understand the difference between hashing and encryption.  I even said as such in my footnote.  I just didn't see the "hash" function and found that "encrypt" claimed to support MD5, SHA, and some other hashing algorithms, so I thought that that was just how you had to do it in ColdFusion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are wanting a hash shouldn't you try the [hash function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_h-im_01.html#1105551) in ColdFusion? I end up using the SHA or SHA-256 algorithms, but the MD5 should work using that function.

```
hash(saltTheHash & trim(UserPassword), "SHA")
```

I would only use encrypt if you are wanting to decrypt sometime later. For things like passwords, you don't want to decrypt them so use the hash function instead.

Comment: He should omit the SHA attribute (or use MD5, although it's default) to get the result he wants.  For things *other* than file verification, though, I use SHA as well.

Comment: thanks, i didn't see the hash function when i was browsing the list, and i saw MD5 in the encrypt function, so i thought that how you did it in cf.

Answer (score 7):

Use CF built in "Hash" function. It takes the following format:

```
Hash(string [, algorithm [, encoding ]])
```

The following works:

```
<cfscript>
    val = 1117;
    md5 = Hash(val, "MD5");
</cfscript>
```